# Can a scala dsl be coded to issue its own specialized compilation errors?

Tags: scala, dsl

I have used a few Scala DSL's, and was wondering whether developing one, can also cater for DSL-specific compilation erros. The idea is that a domain specific language would also have domain specific compilation error messaging, aiding the domain expert in getting things right. Is that possible in Scala?

Comment: I believe you can do that kind of thing with [scala macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#reporting-warnings-and-errors) *warning: not for the faint of heart*

Comment: I was thinking also about issuing specialized messages for things not controlled via macros, to the best of my knowledge. Things like 
type mismatch compilation erros, improper use of an operator... does that require forking the compiler itself or does the compiler have any instrumentation api or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

One of the things that might be useful is [annotation.implicitNotFound](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.implicitNotFound). You can customize compiler errors on unresolved implicits with it's help.

As @Dylan pointed out, if you're hacking Scala with macroses [you can use](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#reporting-warnings-and-errors) `c.abort`, `c.info` and `c.error` to make compiller yield some custom error/extra info.

In this case [annotation.compileTimeOnly](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly) might also be helpful. It allows to restrict usage of some parts of your code and produce custom error message if someone tries to access it.

Comment: Any compiler instrumentation/api that can take this all further?

Comment: There is no one that I am aware of.